# Apache doesn't show filesize/duration during downloading .dmg in browser?

Tags: apache, filesize

I have a .dmg on my website for a Mac Software, but when i try to download this (even in different browsers), it doesn't show me the duration or the filesize. Could this be something i need to configure in Apache?

I checked the http header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK =>
Date => Mon, 22 Apr 2013 15:36:08 GMT
Server => Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 PHP/5.3.22
Last-Modified => Thu, 11 Apr 2013 13:30:19 GMT
ETag => "2087eb-4151ab7-4da15c9a450c0"
Accept-Ranges => bytes
Content-Length => 68491959
Cache-Control => max-age=1209600
Expires => Mon, 06 May 2013 15:36:08 GMT
Vary => Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection => close
Content-Type => application/x-apple-diskimage
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this to your .htaccess :

> SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary